# installing package using loop in ansible

Tags: ansible

I need to use with_items loop to install apache2, sqlite3, and git in Ansible. I'm trying to use the below code but it seems like nothing is happening.

```
---
- hosts: all
  sudo: yes
  name: install apache2, sqlite3, git on remote server
  tasks:
  - name: Install list of packages
    action: apt pkg={{item}} state=installed
    with_items:
      - apache2
      - sqlite3
      - git
```

Comment: ---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  name: install apache2, sqlite3, git pn remote server
  tasks:
  - name: Install list of packages
    action: apt pkg={{item}} state=installed
    with_items:
      - apache2
      - sqlite3
      - git

Comment: Welcome to SO! Remove this comment. It's redundant. Don't comment on your question. Instead, edit your question if you want to update it. See [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work).

Answer (score 2):

you have to place the variable **item** inside the double quotes...
Try this code it'll work:

```
---
- name: install apache2, sqlite3, git on remote servers
  hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: Install packages
      package:
        name: "{{item}}"
        state: present
      loop:
        - apache2
        - sqlite3
        - git
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
---
- name: install apache2, sqlite3, git on remote servers
  hosts: all
  sudo: true
  tasks:
    - name: Install packages
      package:
        name: {{ item }}
        state: present
      loop:
        - apache2
        - sqlite3
        - git
```

See [package – Generic OS package manager](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_module.html#package-generic-os-package-manager)

> *"This module actually calls the pertinent package modules for each system (apt, yum, etc)."*

See [apt – Manages apt-packages](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html#apt-manages-apt-packages) if you need apt specific attributes.